# Key binding fails (command not available)

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2019

I've created a custom keyboard shortcut chord:

[image]

However, when I execute it I get this error in the Visual Studio 2019 status bar:

> The key combination (Ctrl+T,F) is bound to command (.TestExplorer.RunFailedTests) which is not currently available.

No shortcut was previously bound to the command prior to my assignment.

Is there a way to determine why the command isn't available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that was quick.

When creating the binding, we have to select the scope for which the command is available. In this case, certain commands are only available to the Test Explorer:

[image]

Once the Test Explorer pane is selected, it works like a charm.